# Console giving invalid syntax to print function on reddit Bot

Tags: python, reddit

The console is giving a syntax error on line 2 at the end of the word print on the T.

The line by itself functions perfectly.  Some of the code is left out as it contains account details but none of it is relevant to the problem.

```
def run_bot(posts_replied_to):
print ("Searching last 5 posts...")
for submission in praw.Reddit(username = "Sir_Hanush_of_Leipa",
            password = "********",
            client_id = "kbe2veBF1yE9mA",
            client_secret = "*************",
            user_agent = "******".subreddit("kingdomcome").new(limit=5)
    if (submission.id) not in posts_replied_to :
        print ('New post found: ' + submission.id)
        submission.reply(random.choice(kingdom_quotes) + "\n\n___\n\nHalt!
I am ...")
        print ("Replied to post " + submission.id)

        posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)

        with open ("posts_replied_to.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(submission.id + "\n")
        #Pause for 1 minute
        print("Sleeping for 10 minutes...")
        time.sleep(600)
print ("Search Completed.")

print (posts_replied_to)

print("Sleeping for 10 minutes...")
time.sleep(600)

def get_saved_posts():
   if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
    posts_replied_to = []
   else:
     with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
        posts_replied_to = f.read()
        posts_replied_to = posts_replied_to.split("\n")
        posts_replied_to = list(filter(None, posts_replied_to))
    f.close()
return posts_replied_to

def login_ritual():
posts_replied_to = get_saved_posts()
print (posts_replied_to)
return posts_replied_to

while True:
   posts_replied_to = login_ritual()
try:
    run_bot(posts_replied_to)
except:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("Unable to execute. Trying again...")
```

It should use the Reddit API to get the post id and check it to see if the bot has already responded. But it gives a syntax error on the print function.

Edit: This is the error Command prompt gives

```
  File "Kingdombot.py", line 30
print ('New post found: ' + submission.id)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you have a colon `:` after the print but not after the if?

Comment: When I put a colon after the if statement it also gives a syntax error

Comment: the colon needs to be after the if statement not the print

Comment: It doesn't work when I do that either it just gives me a syntax error on the colon.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided the full stacktrace, and the surrounding code.

Comment: I have provided the rest of the code.